# Permanently combine write stream with transform stream?

Tags: node.js

I have a write stream and a transform stream that I always want to use like so:

```
transform.pipe(writeable)
```

And then much later I could get around to piping a readable stream into that.

However because pipe causes reads to be triggered the above pipe immediately crashes because `transform` is not a readable stream.

How can I create a writeable stream that always has a particular `transform` that always precedes it?

For example I want to write all my application's logs to a file, but I want those logs to always be upper case, and the read streams I read from come and go, but the write stream always exists.

Typically this is the error I get:

`Error: Cannot pipe. Not readable.`

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple - your transform stream must either be an instance of [Transform](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform) stream or Duplex - then it'll be both Readable and Writable at the same time.

This way

```
readable.pipe(transform);
```

and then

```
transform.pipe(someFileIJustFoundAbout);
```

would work nicely.

If you'd like to make this even easier, you can use my [scramjet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scramjet) module where a transform is defined by a simple method:

```
readable.pipe(new scramjet.DataStream())
    .breakup(bytes)             // breakup into bytes length
    .map((a) => modify(a))      // do something with the data
    .pipe(writeable);           // write it somewhere
```